# Access remaining records other than records in transaction SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to achieve a task in SQL Server. I'm sharing the sample problem as I couldn't share the entire task description.

**Problem:** we have a table called `Person` as follows:

```
Person_Id   Person_Name   Person_Age
---------   -----------   ----------
        1           AAA           25
        2           BBB           25
        3           CCC           25
        4           DDD           25
```

From that table, I want to use the `Person_Id = 4` that is going to be kept inside a `TRANSACTION`.

```
Person_Id   Person_Name   Person_Age
---------   -----------   ----------
        4           DDD           25
```

While performing the above transaction, user wants to access (`INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE`) all the other records (other than `Person_Id = 4`) which are in the table as below:

```
Person_Id   Person_Name   Person_Age
---------   -----------   ----------
        1           AAA           25
        2           BBB           25
        3           CCC           25
```

**What I tried:**

I tried with `NOLOCK, ROWLOCK` but I couldn't achieve this. Kindly help me to achieve this scenario. I have also tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502273/in-sql-server-how-can-i-lock-a-single-row-in-a-way-similar-to-oracles-select). As per this link, using

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
```

the `SELECT` query is fetching the Unmodified data. For example, If I am trying to `UPDATE` the record in a `TRANSACTION` and the record got updated but the `TRANSACTION` is busy with executing other statements.

```
Person_Id   Person_Name   Person_Age
---------   -----------   ----------
        4           DDD           25
```

Now, when other connections are trying to `SELECT` the records in the table, then all other records along with the Record: `Person_Id = 4` (With old value) will get returned.

> SERIALIZABLE Specifies the following:
>
> Statements cannot read data that has been modified but not yet
>   committed by other transactions.

From the above, When I am using `SERIALIZABLE` isolation, it still returns the OLDER Record of `Person_Id = 4`. This I don't want in this case.

I want to get all the other records, other than the records in a `TRANSACTION`.

In other words, If a record(s) is locked in a `TRANSACTION`, then that record(s) should not appear in any other `SELECT STATEMENT EXECUTION` with different connections.

Comment: What do you mean by keep `Person_Id: 4` inside a transaction? Do you mean you want to exclusively lock that row to prevent all other users from viewing or changing it while reading other rows without blocking others?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In SQL Server, how can I lock a single row in a way similar to Oracle's "SELECT FOR UPDATE WAIT"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502273/in-sql-server-how-can-i-lock-a-single-row-in-a-way-similar-to-oracles-select)

Comment: create a view for your table?

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes. You are absolutely correct. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @Vikash, I think you could specify a `WITH (XLOCK, HOLDLOCK)` hint. If you need the other updates be in a different transaction, you'll need to perform that work on a different connection. Not sure what you're actual use case is but you might take a look at a session level application lock so that you don't need to keep a transaction open. Consider the case when a user has the row locked and leaves for the day.